# Use Httpcontext in data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I treid  to  use  HttpContext in dataAceess layer but i cant creat a object from HttpContext

```
 HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
```

I creat a web application and a libery project and i want to use HttpContext  in  libery project like this :

```
public static Context GetContextPerRequest()
   {

       HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
       if (httpContext == null)
       {
           return new Context();
       }
       else
       {
           int contextId = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID;
           int hashCode = httpContext.GetHashCode();
           string key = string.Concat(hashCode, contextId);

           Context context = httpContext.Items[key] as Context;
           if (context == null)
           {
               context = new Context();
               httpContext.Items[key] = context;
           }

           return context;
       }
   }
```

I use .net 4.

Comment: A data access layer should **not** be depending on a UI-oriented component like the `HttpContext`. Doing this strongly ties your "data access layer" to only ASP.NET web applications - you wouldn't be able to use this for a e.g. WCF service or a WPF application.... I would consider this a really, really bad design...

Comment: The easiest solution is to add a reference to System.Web

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve my problem in this way :

1. Add reference to system.web
2. Using system.web; in my data Access layer
3. make a object from GetContextPerRequest() in Method consractor

Answer (score 3):

you can parse `HttpContext.Current` from presentation layer and change your method as below. if you need to find a way to access current http context [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/314393/ASP-NET-Accessing-HttpContext-Current-and-Other-Sy) link will help you.

```
   public static Context GetContextPerRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   {
      ------
      ------
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your question but your code shows some very bad concepts.

What do you expect this will do?

```
int contextId = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID;
int hashCode = httpContext.GetHashCode();
string key = string.Concat(hashCode, contextId);

Context context = httpContext.Items[key] as Context;
if (context == null)
{
    context = new Context();
    httpContext.Items[key] = context;
}
```

`HttpContext` is your safe storage for HTTP request processing in ASP.NET. `HttpContext.Current` returns unique instance for every request and this instance is independent on thread processing the request - even in asynchronous processing the `HttpContext` will flow with your request from thread to thread but you will never have two threads working on the same request (unless you try to spawn your own threads). If you try to spawn your own threads you cannot use this way at all because `HttpContext` instance exists only until the request is processed but your custom thread lifetime can be longer.

So the code you are using is just overcomplicated version of this:

```
Context context = httpContext.Items["Context"] as Context;
if (context == null)
{
    context = new Context();
    httpContext.Items["Context"] = context;
}
```

Also if this code is from your data access layer it is wrong desing. Data access layer deals with data access and should be independent on upper processing - including HTTP request processing. It means that your `GetContextPerRequest` method doesn't belong to data access layer.

Comment: Just read your answer and was wondering if i understand it correctly. Is it possible that two or more threads can be working on the same HttpContext when doing async work and the context is automatically switched/synched (also you could pass HttpContext.Current to a new thread as a parameter)? In that case you should implement a lock when setting the HttpContext.Items[] to make sure it doesn't also happen in one of the other threads?

Comment: Or is it like the Session.Items where the thread executing get an exclusive read/write lock (or a copy) and no other thread can use it until the thread is finished?